# Google Cast icon in ActionBar changed to B+W recently?

Tags: chromecast

Ever since updating my Eclipse Android SDK to the latest versions of:

- Android Support Library 19.1
- Google Play Services 18

So now whenever I build my apps or the sample SDK apps and I am successfully connected to my ChromeCast, the cast button in the ActionBar has changed and is a black and white instead of the blue image like all of the other apps in the play store (and what mine used to be).

Is this a new style?  Or is there something wrong with my build environment?

When I build it:

[image: sample app with monochrome connected icon]

The connected icons used in the play store apps:
[image: other apps when connected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast icons have been redesigned recently; you can look at the section "Cast Icons" [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads) to see what the new ones look like.